# How can I render "day click" event when clicked on "Event Click" in Jquery full calendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

In jquery calendar,we have day click and event click. I am looking to render "day click" only even if the "event" is clicked. I commented the event click in my code to render "day click".Even though On click of the events in that day it's not firing anything. So How can I achieve it?Any suggestions appreciated

Here is sample code

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  allDaySlot: false,
  header: {
    left: 'today prev next',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'agendaWeek,agendaDay'
  },
 //I commented this event click as I don't want
  eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {

  },
  dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, calEvent) {
      //my customized code
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the same function from eventClick and dayClick. for example:

```
eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
    doSomething(calEvent.start);
},

  dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, calEvent) {
      doSomething(date);
  })
```

you can use the event object documentation [here](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/) and the dayclick event document [enter link description here](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/dayClick/).

hope that helps.

Paras

Comment: Thank you I got same idea but i thought if there is any other approach.Working fine no problem